# when i pass 2 different test data in @test annotation and in @afterTest driver.close() i get the connection reset error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when i pass 2 different test data in @test annotation and in @afterTest driver.close() i get the connection reset error and 2nd browser instance is closed

```
public class HomePage extends base {
//WebDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
public void url() throws IOException {
    
    
}

@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void basepagenaviggation(String username,String password,String Text) throws IOException {
    driver=initializeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login");
    // one way inheritance-- extends
    //creating method to that class and invoke methods of it
    //landingPage lp=new landingPage(driver);
    //lp.login().click();
    loginPage lP=new loginPage(driver);
    lP.getUserame().sendKeys(username);
    lP.getPassword().sendKeys(password);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    System.out.println(Text);
    lP.loginButton().click();
    
}
@AfterTest
public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.close();
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData() {
    //rows stands for how many different data types test should run
    //column stands for how many values for each test
    Object[][] data=new Object[2][3];
    //0th row
    data[0][0]="dd@gmail.com";
    data[0][1]="123456";
    data[0][2]="dd user";
    //1st row
    data[1][0]="ff@gmail.com";
    data[1][1]="123456";
    data[1][2]="ff user";
    return data;
    
}
```

error

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.5.0
```

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 59288
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 14, 2022 10:01:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
May 14, 2022 10:01:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 101, so returning the closest version found: 97
May 14, 2022 10:01:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 101 of 97
dd user
Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 53408
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 14, 2022 10:01:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
May 14, 2022 10:01:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 101, so returning the closest version found: 97
May 14, 2022 10:01:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 101 of 97
ff user
May 14, 2022 10:01:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:367)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:398)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

PASSED: basepagenaviggation("ff@gmail.com", "123456", "ff user")
PASSED: basepagenaviggation("dd@gmail.com", "123456", "dd user")

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue which got resolved by giving .quit(); instead of .close();

My suggestion is to avoid using .close();  just use .quit();  which should close the browser and dispose of the WebDriver.